# How to save form uploaded files in a form in a specific folder in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, onsubmit

So, I have trying to save uploaded files in a specific folder. Say, I have an html file as shown:

```
<form>
<input type="file" id="image_file" />
<input type="file" id="text_file" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now, I want to write a js onsubmit function for the above form such that it saves the given file in a unique folder inside a base folder.
I had been researching various ways of doing this, and the only solution I found is using a server by making ajax calls, which I dont want to do.
Is there any native way in javascript that allows me to do this?

Comment: No, you can’t access local file system directly from js. You can trigger a download a let the user select where store the file.

Comment: Read about server side development, there are millions of tutorials about this!

Answer (score 0):

You can not store upload files to the server only using client-side Javascript. You need any backend language/technology. Javascript is the client-side language which runs only in the client's browser, so you need to send the selected file to the server and then save it on the server using any backend language (for example, `php` or 'node.js`)

Check out these links:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp